# laravel mix babel

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack, ecmascript-6

Помогите разобраться. Имеется IE 11, который как я понимаю использует ECMAScipt2015, в котором НЕТ поддержки `exponentiation (**) operator`. То есть, если я напишу 7**2 в хроме я получу 49, а в IE я должен получить фигу. Однако, в процессе сборки через laravel mix (который как я понимаю просто обертка для webpack), я получаю в IE 11 удивительные 49.

То есть все работает... Но зачем тогда в официальной документации laravel есть такое:

```
Mix can automatically install the Babel plug-ins necessary for React support. To get started, replace your mix.js() call with mix.react():

mix.react('resources/js/app.jsx', 'public/js');
Behind the scenes, Mix will download and include the appropriate babel-preset-react Babel plug-in.
```

То есть мне предлагают заменить mix.js на mix.react, чтобы подключился babel и превращал как раз нормальный код к стандарту ecmascript2015. НО у меня в конфиге используется mix.js!
Вопрос, что же по факту происходит? Почему webpack, без моего явного указания конвертирует все это в ES2015? Как это работает вообще

Comment: `Mix can automatically install the Babel plug-ins necessary for React support`. Mix может установить Babel для поддержки React. React - это UI фреймворк. Он мало связан с ecmascript2015.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko да уже покопался как следует. Бабел врублен по умолчанию оказался вообще, про реакт тоже заметил потом, как то пропустил сначала. Правда как выключить бабел так и не нашел

Comment: Вопрос: а зачем его выключать? Ну уж если очень хочется - переопредели конфиг при помощи `mix.webpackConfig({ params })`